# AttributeError: module 'firebase_admin.firestore' has no attribute 'AsyncClient'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio

I am using Firestore in my application and trying to use `Python (Async)` to run operations on Firestore.

I am using the example given in the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize).
I am getting the below error while running `db = firestore.AsyncClient()`.

```
root@54ec5947a266:/usr/src/app# python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 69, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 60, in test
    db = firestore.AsyncClient()
AttributeError: module 'firebase_admin.firestore' has no attribute 'AsyncClient'
root@54ec5947a266:/usr/src/app#
```

Looks like the `AsyncClient` is not found.

```
root@5e2f7f6fc19c:/usr/src/app# python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Apr  5 2021, 09:00:41) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from firebase_admin import firestore
>>> 'AsyncClient' in dir(firestore)
False
>>>
```

Could you please guide me if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncClient` does exist in python's firestore submodoule:

```
>>> from firebase_admin import firestore
>>> 'AsyncClient' in dir(firestore)
True
```

Make sure you have installed python's firease admin library correctly, and for your python and pip version and use [firebase-admin installation guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk).
(e.g. pip3 install --user firebase-admin)

Comment: I have installed the `firebase_admin`, I am getting it as `False` if I try the same command in my system. I have updated the question above.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response, could you please let me if there is any change I need to perform.

Comment: Thank you, I found the issue, I was using Python3.5, as per the requirement minimum version is 3.6.